# "Vector iterator not dereferenceble"......Visual Studio 2010 error

Tags: opencv

> > after morphological operations i  detected the finger tip. the vector fingertips
> >     contain the details of all the finger tip. i created an iterator to get the first and
> >     the second fingertip coordinates.
> >     but when i try to compile i get the error "vector iterator not dereferencable"...
> >
> > please help me !!1

while (1)
{
.
.
vector::iterator p = 0;

```
            p = fingerTips.begin();
            CvPoint forefinger = *p;
            *p++;
            CvPoint secondfinger = *p;

            int distance = secondfinger.y - forefinger.y;
            char dist[6];

            sprintf(x_pt,"%d",forefinger.x);

            sprintf(y_pt,"%d",forefinger.y);

            sprintf(dist,"%d",distance);

            cvPutText(source,dist,cvPoint(220,320), &font, cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0));     

            cvLine(source,cvPoint(forefinger.x,forefinger.y),cvPoint(secondfinger.x,secondfinger.y),cvScalar(255,0,0,0),4,8,0);
```

.
.
.
.
}

Answer (score 0):

Your vector declaration is wrong. It should have been `vector<cv::Point>::iterator p`